# How can I correctly traverse a binary tree in order to return the height of it?

Tags: c#, binary-tree

I have started implementing this code but now I'm stuck. I'm trying to return the height of the tree from the root to the furthest leaf. I'm able to access the outside leaves but not the inner ones. How can I incorporate the inner leaves in my function in order to return the highest height?

```
static int getHeight(Node root){
  int left = 0;
  int right = 0;
  Node head = root;
  while(root.left != null) {
      root = root.left;
      left++;
  }
  while(head.right != null) {
      head = head.right;
      right++;
  }
return Math.Max(left, right);
```

Comment: I'd strongly recommend reading basics (i.e. just https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) before writing code. Alternative approach would be to compute complexity of the code (O(tree_height) for the code shown in the post) and compare with what you'd expect (visit all nodes in full binary tree of given height - O(tree_height ^ 2)  ) and try to come up with code that matches in complexity (or at least more complex than desired, it is *very unlikely* one finds an algorithm that is correct and yet so much faster than expected)

Comment: I appreciate the info. I will look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this recursive algorithm:

```
static int getHeight(Node root){
    int left = 0;
    int right = 0;
    if(root==null) return 0
    left = getHeight(root.left)+1;
    right= getHeight(root.right)+1;
    return Math.Max(left, right);
}
```

Comment: You can put it very concise: `static int getHeight(Node root) => root == null ? 0 : Math.Max(getHeight(node.left), getHeight(node.right)) + 1;`

Comment: Thanks. I will implement this immediately and learn from it.

Comment: This worked. I just had to change return 0 to return -1 otherwise I wasn't getting the correct height.

Answer (score 0):

You can try, say, **B**readth **F**irst **S**earch (**BFS**), let it be non-recursive approach (since you want to traverse):

```
static int getHeight(Node root) {
  if (root == null)
    return 0;

  Queue<Node> agenda = new Queue<Node>();

  agenda.Enqueue(root);

  int result = 0; 

  while (agenda.Count > 0) {
    result += 1;

    for (int i = agenda.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
      var node = agenda.Dequeue();

      if (node.left != null)
        agenda.Enqueue(node.left);
      if (node.right != null)
        agenda.Enqueue(node.right);
    }
  } 

  return result; 
}
```

Comment: @Orace: Thank you! My bad, I've really forgot to put `agenda.Enqueue(root);`

Comment: @Orace: we can't just increment in inner `for`: please, note, that we `Enqueue` items, and that's why *change* `agenda.Count`, in case of reversed `for` we get `agenda.Count` just once before any potential `Enqueue`

Comment: @Orace: it's a opinion based: from my point of view - it's a typical pattern to *loop backward* when collection can be *changed within the loop* (another typical example is removing from collection within a `for` loop). As for `agenda` - agenda (scope of work, items) for processing.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I haven't thought about using a queue. I'll play around with this.